# Efficient Minimax chess engine in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, functional-programming

For the sake of the conversation I would rather implement [Minimax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) and not Alpha-beta or any other algorithm.

I implemented this already in OOP fashion (CPP). Instead of having the Minimax tree nodes to be entire deep-clones of the board, I found out it is more efficient the edges are just *deltas* between boards (an interface that allows `Do()` and `Undo()` on a board) and the board state is calculated on the fly.

When I travel through the tree I apply these `Delta`s' on my one and only instance of the board.

How should I address this in functional-programming immutable style? Cloning the entire board every time was definitely slower than just changing one instance of the board.

I'm new to functional programming and I'm still trying to get my head around this way of thinking.

Comment: A programmer normally writes code that prevent a *full deep copy* of the data, like a *fingertree* for example that only creates *O(log n)* extra nodes when you insert something in the tree and thus uses the "old" nodes for the new tree as well.

Comment: In other words, it is thus important to make a data structure where moving one of the pieces will only update a limited amount of "data nodes" for that board, and thus reuses the rest of the data structure.

Comment: "*I found out it is more efficient*" - what efficiency are you actually concerned about? Memory efficiency? Time efficiency of creating the tree? of traversing the tree? of evaluating the tree nodes? Notice that what you found out for your C++ program might not hold for a different approach in Haskell. Of course you *can* use exactly the same approach in Haskell, but it'll look like a C++ program in a weird syntax, not like functional programming.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem but what data structure can I use to represent the board in such way?

Comment: @Bergi all in all I want my engine to iterate through as many positions as possible (given standard PC hardware, and Minimax algorithm). All considerations apply. I agree with your last sentence. I want to approach this correctly but I can't find the way.

Comment: In eager languages you have to come up with all sorts of tricks to deal with your situation - one method is to `Do` and `Undo` some actions on your state, another method could be to represent state deltas with a seperate type. In a lazy functional language like Haskell, you get this (mostly) for free - when your state update is isolated to a small part of the state, you can just do the update and let sharing do the rest. Of course it's possible to make accidental copies but you should profile your program to see if this does in fact occur.

Comment: @user2407038 It's not technically the lazy/eager distinction that matters for what you're talking about. Eager languages can use sharing just as easily as lazy ones. e.g. in Java the fields of a class will generally be references to other objects, so you can make a shallow copy of the object that shares the other objects, just like sharing the values in a Haskell ADT. Rather it's the *pure* part; languages with untracked impurity tend not use as many algorithms that rely on lots of sharing, because losing track of when *mutable* structures are shared is a debugging nightmare.

Comment: I think haskell by default uses shallow copies. _Please, confirm with more experienced users that I am right, because I not so pro at haskell_: So let say you implement your board as `Data.Map (Int, Int) Cell` (i.e. a set of `Cell`s indexed by a pair of `Int`s. Equivalent to python's dictionary). If you use `insert` to update the state of a `Cell`, you get a new `Map`  which is a shallow copy of the first, meaning that old and new maps share references as much as posible, so you are not cloning the whole board, but just modifying one cell and sharing the unchanged part with the old one...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem how would you represent the board then? Do you agree with Ismor suggest?